# Canonical pattern reference in Actors programming model

Tags: scala, f#, erlang, actor, canonical-schema

Is there a source, which I could use to learn some of the most used and popular practices regarding Actor-/Agent-oriented programming? My primary concern is about parallelism and distribution limited to the mentioned scheme - Actors, message passing.

Should I begin with Erlang documentation or maybe there is any kind of book that describes the most important building blocks when programming Actor-oriented?

(Most useful examples would be in Scala or F#)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a colorful and interesting explanation I'd recommend to read some entries on this [blog](http://www.dalnefre.com/wp/)

Other than that, we welcome you to the Akka mailinglist!

Comment: Hi :) And I'm very glad that your response is right to the point. I'll be the subscriber to the blog you mentioned and surely employ Akka in my future works, I hope.

Answer (score 5):

The Erlang and Scala's Akka are most popular and have large community. In case you want to know ML-based style there is [JoCaml](http://jocaml.inria.fr). They have [simple intro text](http://jocaml.inria.fr/manual/concurrent.html) and collection of more formal papers. I'm using JoCaml about two years in my research work and very happy with it. Also, you can find many examples of the F# mailboxes usage to implement actor-style message passing.

Comment: Interesting note about JoCaml, happy to see that you use it. And about F# mailboxes there are indeed many examples, but I wanted some more high-level and general patterns (e.g. failover management, inter-agent negotiotions etc.). thx!

Answer (score 4):

With regards to the usage of Actors in Scala, you might want to look into the [Akka](http://doc.akkasource.org/) framework. It has good documentation, and [here](http://doc.akkasource.org/articles) they have a list of articles and presentations with many examples.

Comment: Your hint is very helpful, cause I want just now looking into the Akka framework. And to hear that it's popular brings hope. However, I would like to enhance my _knowledge_ of the mentioned patterns, not just use them. Thx :)

Answer (score 3):

You won't find much in the Erlang documentation that explicitly talks about Actors. The documentation and recent Erlang books explain how to use concurrency/distribution/message passing in the Erlang context. As an aside we hadn't actually heard of Actors when we developed Erlang.